# Get all tables, views and stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 different databases in my SQL Server.

```
Db1
Db2
Db3
```

I have almost 70 tables, 30 views and 50 stored procedures in each databases.

1. Is there a way to list all tables, views and stored procedures along with databases?
2. While getting views and stored procedures, is there a way to get what all the tables that are used in them?

   Example: `view1` in `Db1` has used 2 tables (1 from Db1 and another from Db2).
   So can we list these tables?
3. Similar to views, the same for stored procedures as well

Is these possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

start with

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects

SELECT * FROM sysdepends

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
```

you should be able to figure it out easily